# c# stackoverflow Exception

Tags: c#

Решил поексперементировать и написал вот такой код:

```
class FailSoftArray
{

    public int length
    {
        get
        {
            return length;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value > 10)
            {
                length = value;

            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("There is some error,please try again!");
            }
        }     
    }

}
```

При попытке присвоения какого-либо значения полю length выскакивает ошибка

> "Procces is terminated due to StackOverFlowException".

Я так понимаю, переполнился стек,но почему?

Comment: Свойство должно возвращать какую-то переменную, а не само себя.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return length;
...
length = value;
```

Вот эти строки рекурсивно вызывают сами себя, что приводит к бесконечному количеству вызовов, а следовательно, к переполнению стека.
Сделайте что-нибудь вроде этого:

```
private int _length;
public int length  
{  
    get  
    {  
        return _length;  
    }  
    set  
    {  
        if (value > 10)  
        {  
            _length = value;  

        }  
        else  
        {  
            Console.WriteLine("There is some error,please try again!");  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Да, я знаю, что в таком случае всё будет работать без проблем. Мне было интересно именно почему при моём експерименте я ловил ошибку, теперь мне понятно.

Comment: @Castiel_Luciefer2000 можно было бы пошагово пройтись отладчиком и всё стало бы понятно.

Comment: @alexolut Согласен с Вами, но обратиться за помощью на этот сайт - первое что пришло в голову.